# How to use a base layout and custom it in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'am trying to create a Linear Layout and an editText base on a layout.xml file here is the java code :

```
private EditText editText(int _intID) {
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.player_name);
        editText.setId(_intID);
        editText.setHint("Element "+_intID);
        editTextList.add(editText);

        return editText;
    }

    private LinearLayout linearlayout(int _intID)
    {

        LinearLayout LLMain= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_player_base);

        LLMain.setId(_intID);
        LLMain.addView(editText(_intID));

        LLMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearlayoutList.add(LLMain);
        return LLMain;

    }
```

Here is the xml layout I want to use as a base :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/linear_player_base">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/player_name"
    android:background="@drawable/input"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't understand why when I do :

```
LinearLayout LLMain= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_player_base);
and then :
```

LLMain.setId(_intID);

I have this error : `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setId(int)' on a null object reference`

why LLMain is null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must inflate a custom view with you layout and the find the linear layout in this view...
Do it like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playerLayout, null);

LinearLayout LLMain= (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linear_player_base);
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded this xml file that you want to use as base ??

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutNameHere);
```

Comment: I have my main layout set like this : 
   setContentView(R.layout.MainLayout);
But this layout is a second one called : playerLayout I need to set it too ?